# Adding and Removing Div inside a Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show an alert on my modal (from bootstrap) about the account entered by the user (e.g *Invalid Account*).

However, (for example, I entered a wrong account) after getting an error response and prepend it and then enter a wrong account again, it won't remove the previous alert i prepend.

Here's what's happening:
[image: Prepends alert every time i click the button]

Here's my HTML Code:

```html
<div class="modal-body modal-login">
  <?php include( 'login.php'); ?>
  <form name="test" action="" method="post" role="form" id="loginForm">
    <input type="text" class="form-control userTB" name="loginText" placeholder="Username/Email" required>
    <input type="password" class="form-control passTB" name="passText" placeholder="Password" required>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="submit_button">Login</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```js
jQuery(function ($){
    $('#submit_button').click(function(){
        var post_url = 'login.php';

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : post_url,
            data: $('#loginForm').serialize(),
            dataType : 'html',
            async: true,
            success : function(data){
             $('.modal-login').remove('.alert');
                $('.modal-login').prepend(data);
            }
        });
    })           
});
```

**Note**: That `data` from jQuery contains `<div class="alert alert-danger">Wrong Account!</div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(el).remove(selector)` is somewhat confusing. It basically means "remove `el` from the document *if* it matches `selector`". This makes more sense if your jQuery object has multiple elements and you're filtering which ones to remove.

If you change your code to `.remove('.modal-login')`, you'll see that it removes the whole modal.

You should use `.find` then `.remove`:

```
$('.modal-login').find(".alert").remove();
$('.modal-login').prepend(data);
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. I used `$(el).remove(selector)` because that's what i read from the jQuery documentation. Thank you so much. Will mark this as answer after 4mins.